# Messages on Mac say not sending but they are going through

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

I've tried changing my addresses on my phone, logging in and out, and messing with the library setting in finder. I know that the messages are being received and it happens all the time to almost everyone I message thru my comuter (and im receiveing all the messages on my phone as well.) It's just annoying really but not an actual problem.

[image]